# Quelles sont les insultes basées sur des fruits et légumes

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, insultes

Je cherche des insultes basées sur des noms de fruits et légumes.

Qu'est-ce que vous proposez (et connaissez-vous l'origine?)

Comment: [Yahoo! answers](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080506051946AAgd0yx) en connaît. [Et d'autres…](http://www.icem-pedagogie-freinet.org/book/export/html/3209)

Comment: @Evpok "_je viens-tu des choux_" n'est utilisé que sur cette Yahoo answer. Et "_avoir l'air d'une échalotte_ (sic, il n'y a qu'un `t`)" n'est utilisé que sur une autre page. J'ai donc quelques doutes sur l'usage de ces expressions… Quant à "_tête de gland_", je ne suis pas sûr que l'on parle du fruit…

Answer (score 3):

- **banane** : idiot, imbécile

  > c'est pas du tout ça, banane
- **patate**: idiot, imbécile
- **courge** : idiot, imbécile, ne réagissant pas

  > elle a vu le verre glisser et l'a laissé tomber, cette courge
- **asperge** : grand

  > c'est pas possible, une asperge pareille, avoir par-dessus le marché, un coeur d'artichaut

  (*Exercice de style*, Raymond Queneau)
- **face de citron**: Chinois
- **face d'ananas** (sens?)